# GH-Pages, background image do not display

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I understand its a common question, hovever i tried couple pathes to my image and it still wont work.

My GH structure: https://github.com/Dev-And-Rew/GrandHotel
i have tried below and nothing helps:

CSS File:

```
 url("../img/nav-bg.jpeg") center no-repeat
 url("./img/nav-bg.jpeg") center no-repeat
 url("/img/nav-bg.jpeg") center no-repeat
 url("img/nav-bg.jpeg") center no-repeat
```

Comment: Using relative path `./img/nav-bg.jpeg` worked for me

Comment: for image use `backgroud-img` for gradient use `background` tag

Comment: Yea,  i was changing nav img but was looking on banner img ( which was not fixed yet).... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I entered the link that you provided to us in the repository and put (.) before the link and everything worked normally
[See the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJYGM.png)